# AlertDialog - proper way to build it. Now blink and flick opening

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, flicker

In my project I am using a simple AlertDialog to enter some information.
My problem is that when I go to open this AlertDialog I have a flicker for a very short time which is not correct. I would like to know what I'm wrong and above all what should be the correct way to build it because I can't find a solution around, if not that of changing objects. But I would really need the AlertDialog

```
    private void insertNameManually(String hint, int mType) {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog, null);
    EditText editText = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    Button clearTextButton = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.clearText);
    Button confirmButton = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.confirmButton);
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
    dialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.std_choose);
    confirmButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        name = editText.getText().toString();

        name = hint;
        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
            MyFragment.this.type = mType;
            Intent data = new Intent();
            data.putExtra("type", type);
            activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
            activity.finish();
        }, 275);
    });

    editText.setText(hint);

    clearTextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editText.setText("");
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:** You can try by adding flag to your alert dialog,  `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED;`

You can try by switching to a `DialogFragment` can help to remove the flicker.

Tip:
Just want add here by looking at your code instead of,

```
  AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
  alertDialog.show();
```

You can do this way, will create and show the alert dialog.

```
dialogBuilder.show();
```

Comment: adding FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED would not seem to improve. The second Tip, why could help me? Why could work? Thanks in advance

Comment: @DoctorWho Basically, Alert Dialog we use only for Informative purpose only like to show message to the user. On the other hand, when we want to carry a custom view  like TextView, edit text or something more complex ui then DialogFragment is recommended to use.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I have a `DialogFragment` with a `TextInputLayout`, acting as a button. When pressed, it shows an `AlertDialog` window that flickered / flashed when opened.

Somewhere on the website (sorry, forgot source) I found a hint for why the dialog flickers - I believe it's because both the `DialogFragment` and `AlertDialog` set a dim background when shown.

The solution that worked for me was to disable the dimming by the `AlertDialog`. The background was still dimmed between the base `Fragment` and the `DialogFragment`, but not between the `DialogFragment` and `AlertDialog`. This may or may not be a desirable effect, in my case it was fine.

To remove said dimming effect, you need to clear the `FLAG_DIM_BEHIND` flag for the window. I'm doing that just before I show the dialog.

Java:

```
  AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
  alertDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHI‌​ND);
  alertDialog.show();
```

Kotlin:

```
  val dialog = builder.create()
  dialog.window?.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND)
  dialog.show()
```